# How can I use a SpringBoot RestController on a separate Java Class to query database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am fairly new to SpringBoot so please fill free to fill in the details where needed.

I wrote this [Rest Controller](https://github.com/fabiogomezdiaz/refarch-cloudnative-micro-inventory/blob/master/src/main/java/inventory/mysql/InventoryController.java) in a SpringBoot app, which works as expected. My questions is, how can I properly create an instance of this controller so that I can use it to query the database?

I was trying to do something like this, but just kept getting errors.

```
InventoryController ic = new InventoryController();
System.out.println(ic.getInventory());
```

I am trying to avoid a situation where I have to do a REST call on the SpringBoot app itself.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

It is not considered to be a good practice to perform the database calls on the controller. You can either use a Spring Data Repository, or write a Service Layer code that utilizes the repository(which performs the calls on the database)

One might do it as follows

```
@Service
public class InventoryService {
  @Autowire
  private IInventoryItemRepo inventoryItemRepo;

  @Transactional
  public List<Inventory> getInventories() {
    //other business rules
    return inventoryItemRepo.findAll();
   }
  //some other logic here
}
```

and then on your controller

```
    @RestController
    public class InventoryController {

        Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(InventoryController.class);

        @Autowired
        private InventoryService inventoryService;
        /**
         * @return all items in inventory
         */
        @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="failGood")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/inventory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody Iterable<Inventory> getInventory() {
            return inventoryService.findAll();
        }
           ....

    }
```

If you want to avoid performing the call on the spring you can inject the service layer code to that component who would be performing the call assuming it is written on java with Spring.

If not you can also build a [Message Queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)
 and send the message there.

An alternative is this one called [Spring Data REST](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/)

Answer (score 1):

You do not use controller directly to query database OR it is not a good practice to do so.

One better option is that you can utilize **Spring data repository** and `@Autowire` it in your controller.

What I normally do is that I create a **service class**, in which a **repository inteface** is autowired. In the controller, I autowire the **service class**.

My answer of the following post might clear up more things for you:
[Structure of RESTful Service with Java Spring for Beginner](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323571/structure-of-restful-service-with-java-spring-for-beginner/)